# Open some site pages from WebView in an external browser

Tags: java, android, webview

The application displays the site page. To go to external links in an external browser, use the following:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();

        if(url.contains("mysite.com") && !url.contains("tracker") && !url.contains("contact")) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I also need to open some of the pages (tracker.php & contact.php) hosted on this site via a link in an external browser.

The solution above does not work, all pages from this site open in the application itself.

Tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the above code works.
It was enough to clear the cache.

At the time of application development, I installed a button for clearing the cache and other things:

```
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            WebView.clearHistory();
            WebView.clearFormData();
            WebView.clearCache(true);
            WebView.reload();
        }
    });
```